# How to use Windows key in Ubuntu 9.10 to open Gnome Panel menu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just installed Ubuntu 9.10 onto a Lenovo T61.  I can't seem to map the Windows key to bring up the Gnome Panel menu (Ubuntu's equivalent of a Start menu).  I've tried System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts, navigating to 'Desktop > Show the panel's main menu' but when I get there and hit the Windows key, nothing happens.  It looks like it's only being seen as a modifier key; if I hit `<Windows>-<1>` then it binds to `Mod4+1`.  xev shows the following when I press the Windows key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 30819302, (200,-9), root:(1150,37),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 30819470, (200,-9), root:(1150,37),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

It's been *way* too many years since I've messed with xmodmap and the like.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing around I found the answer:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Just as an aside, setting up the Windows key in this manner prevents its use as a modifier key.  It can only be used by itself.  XP was able to deal with both uses, sadly.

Comment: this saved my day :) but here is another issue. If I click again the menu doesn't close. Have you found a workaround for this?

Comment: @bakytn - hit the escape key; don't know of anything else, sorry.